# Undoing All Changes Since BindingSource's last EndEdit call

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, ado.net, bindingsource

Here's the scenario (which uses a BindingSource bound to a DataTable within a DataSet):

1. A user creates a new address book
   contact, fills in the First and Last
   name in data-bound controls.
2. He presses Apply, whose event
   handler calls
   BindingSource.EndEdit().
3. He then realizes there was a
   mistake, and adds an email address.
4. But when he presses Apply,
   validation fails (invalid email
   format), so EndEdit() isn't called.
5. He decides not to make the edit, and
   presses the Cancel button, whose
   event handler calls
   BindingSource.CancelEdit().
6. But, rather than reverting to the
   new contact with just a First and
   Last name and no email, the
   BindingSource has instead gotten rid
   of the entire record.

Is there any way to only undo actions since the last time EndEdit() was called? I was under the impression that's how CancelEdit() was supposed to work.

Comment: I had a similar problem, so I'll be interested to see if you get a good answer for this. My workaround was to call EndEdit() on the DataRowView object directly.

Comment: When you call it on the DataRowView, what does the DataRowState change to? Is it still Added, or does it become either Modified or Unchanged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an explanation, the DataTable only holds 2 states for a record, the Original and Current. Your request would require multiple states.

To achieve what you want you should flush the changes to the database (eg Adapter.Update(table)) in response to a successful Apply. That promotes your Current to Original and the next Cancel can fall back to that.

This may or may not match your requirements though.

Comment: Right, the problem is that I only call Adapter.Update() when the data gets persisted to the database.

Comment: What I guess I'll have to do is to keep my own temporary copy of each row before the user begins an edit operation, and write the values back to the row if they "cancel".